# Use twisted with custom main loop

Tags: python, twisted

I have an existent main loop which I'm not able (and do not want actually) to change.
Basically it's based on callback-timers system.

At the same time I would like to use some twisted functionality, especially twisted sockets. As far as I can block my app with `reactor.run()` I have in my mind idea of using `reactor.iterate()` however I don't think it would do exactly what I need.

I need to have possibility to 'scroll' reactor once per call, to check all DelayedCalls. The thing is I want to do it just once.

Could you please advice is there way to do it? In fact "Man, this is madness, it won't workm no way" is also an answer, however I would prefer some a bit more useful.

P.S. I've read [Use my own main loop in twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303600/use-my-own-main-loop-in-twisted) and I don't think there's the way to do what I need there.

Comment: You have not explained what you need in a way that would allow us to gove advise. Please add some code so we can see what you have.

Comment: Re-read the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303600/use-my-own-main-loop-in-twisted - the answer specified there is exactly what you need.